# Assumption of SINR measurement

Tags: digital-communications

I am assuming there is an Access Point (AP) and IoT Nodes in NOMA uplink scenario. Following is assumed:

1. the AP does not know the channel gain of IoT Nodes
2. the transmission power of nodes is also unknown to AP

   - How can we measure the SINR of the nodes: as we do not have the **Power x Gain** product without the knowledge of Power and Gain of IoT nodes.
   - Is it right to assume that the receiver of the AP won't be able to get any legible data (information) unless the SINR is above a certain threshold?

Answer (score 2):

> How can we measure the SINR of the nodes: as we do not have the Power x Gain product without the knowledge of Power and Gain of IoT nodes.

Not at all, you have zero information about the N in SINR, and without channel knowledge you also can't have any information on the S, nor the I, even if you knew the transmit powers (which you don't).

> Is it right to assume that the receiver of the AP won't be able to get any legible data (information) unless the SINR is above a certain threshold?

Yes. If you're into NOMA, you should be aware of a bit of basic information theory (otherwise, it's hard to understand why you'd even ever *want* to go non-orthogonal):

In this case, a very basic corner case of the Shannon Limit holds true. Some call it the *ultimate Shannon Limit*, but what it really just says is that if your bit energy is below -1.59 dB of the energy of your redundancy, you can't get *any* information from your reception.

In a multi-user system, one can (often iteratively) gain information about the interference¹, but if noise² alone pushes the SINR below -1.59 dB, you've lost and better redesign your system.

---

¹Thus reducing restoring the receiver's ability to "remove" parts of the entropy the interferer adds to the received signal.

²"Noise" actually being all entropy in the reception that doesn't come from the information source. That incorporates all entropy of interference that you can't "cancel", however that happens.

Comment: Thankou very Much Sir!. I appreciate your reply and it pretty much answers my question.

Comment: then please click on the "accept" checkmark on this answer. That marks your question as answered (also, it gives you and me a few points, but I don't care about that much).